# How to get notifications about failovers in Redis cluster to the client application

Tags: redis, jedis

Is there a way for a client to get notified about failover events in the Redis cluster? If so, which client library would support this? I am currently using Jedis but have the flexibility to switch to any other Java client.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways that I can think of to check this, one of them is to grep for master nodes on the cluster, [keeping in mind their IDs](http://redis.io/commands/cluster-nodes#serialization-format), if the ports changed for any of them then a failover happened.

```
$ redis-cli -p {PORT} cluster nodes | grep master
```

Another way, but it is not as robust of a solution is using the [consistency checker](http://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial#a-more-interesting-example-application) ruby script, that will start showing errors in writes as an output, which you can monitor and send notifications depending on it, since that happens when the read server is trying to take its master's role.

Answer (score -3):

Sentinel (http://redis.io/topics/sentinel) has the ability to monitor the cluster member, and send a publish/subscribe notification upon failure. The link contains a more in-depth explanation and tutorial.

Comment: Sentinel with cluster can be used?